# Apps script to force specific row height in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I couldn't find the way in apps script to force specific row height in google sheet. When I use ".setRowHeight(rowPosition, height)", it always auto resize the row height to fit the font size. But I would like it in specific height of my need as shown in pictures. Thanks you for any helps.

from this:
[image: from this]

I would like it to look like this by apps script.
[image: to this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to modify the row height by the size you set.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

In this answer, I used "updateDimensionProperties" of Sheets API. When you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var height = 200; // Please set the height as the unit of pixel.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // or ss.getActiveSheet()
  var resource = {requests: [{
    updateDimensionProperties: {
      properties: {pixelSize: height},
      range: {sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), startIndex: 2, endIndex: 3, dimension:"ROWS"},
      fields:"pixelSize"
    }}]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this case, `startIndex: 2, endIndex: 3` means the row 3.

#### Note:

- If you want to modify the column width, please modify `dimension` to `COLUMNS`.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Row and Column Operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn)
- [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a method .setRowHeightsForced() [Documentation](https://Documnetation%20https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setrowheightsforcedstartrow,-numrows,-height)

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// Sets the first three rows to a height of 5 pixels.
sheet.setRowHeightsForced(1, 3, 5);
```